# Google Photos API mediaItems list/search methods ignore pageSize param

Tags: google-photos-api

I am attempting to do a retrieve of all media items that a given Google Photos user has, irrespective of any album(s) that they are in. However when I attempt to use either the [`mediaItems.list`](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest/v1/mediaItems/list) or the [`mediaItems.search`](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest/v1/mediaItems/search) methods, the `pageSize` param I am including in either request is either being ignored or not fully fullfilled.

**Details of `mediaItems.list` request**

```
GET https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems?pageSize=<###>
```

**Details of `mediaItems.search` request**

```
POST https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems:search
BODY { 'pageSize': <###> }
```

I have made a simple implementation of these two requests here as an example for this question, it just requires a valid `accessToken` to use:
https://jsfiddle.net/zb2htog1/

Running this script with the following `pageSize` against a Google Photos account with 100s of photos and 10s of albums consistently returns the same unexpected amount of result for both methods:

| Request pageSize | Returned media items count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 25 | 9 |
| 50 | 17 |
| 100 | 34 |

I know that Google states the following for the `pageSize` parameter for both of these methods:

> “Maximum number of media items to return in the response. Fewer media
> items might be returned than the specified number. The default
> pageSize is 25, the maximum is 100.”

I originally assumed that the reason fewer media items might be returned is because an account might have less media items in total than a requested `pageSize`, or that a request with a `pageToken` has reached the end of a set of paged results. However I am now wondering if this just means that results may vary in general?

Can anyone else confirm if they have the same experience when using these methods without an album ID for an account with a suitable amount of photos to test this? Or am I perhaps constructing my requests in an incorrect fashion?

Comment: I have also noticed that when not requesting a page size, the methods return 9 media items instead of the 25 suggested in the official documentation. This feels like there could be a bug in the API, as when 25 are requested, again 9 are consistently returned.

Answer (score 0):

I experience something similar. I get back half of what I expect.
If I don't set the pageSize, I get back just 13, If I set to 100, I get back 50.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).